# Using activation code for authentication on Android App

Tags: android

It possible to provide an activation code for android app? This activation code will be provided with a physical product being sold in retail outlet. Only User with the activation code will be able to activate and use the android App corresponding to this product.

I read google policy but was unable to find the answer to this question. I understand for in-store & in-app purchase we need to use Google Payment system.

Also, if possible, can this activation be done via server?

PS: I am not seeking a solution to avoid google's policy/margins but the nature of product being sold has a special android app that only specific users can use.

Answer (score 1):

I know a solution for this scene,it is widely used in my company.
Step1:Prepare a signed Apk.
Step2:Read your marked text such as "ActivationCode_xxxx" from a file or 
a download URL param.
Step3:Create an empty file named "ActivationCode_xxxx" in APK/META-INF/.
Step4:Get the activation code by reading that fileName at the first time launching the application.This is a special app with "ActivationCode_xxxx".

Comment: I could not understand the relation between a activation code and "ActivationCode_xxxx" from a file. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: 'from a file' is just a channel for reading generated activation codes.According to 'This activation code will be provided with a physical product being sold in retail outlet',it can create numerous Apks with different activation codes before being sold.Did this help you?

Comment: By the way you shared, apk will have to be distributed separately and customer will not get it from the market/(google play store).  Am I right?

Comment: 'apk will have to be distributed separately' is absolutely true.But I said 'from a download URL param',it means that apk can be dynamic generated when user try download it.I think it must have some differences between two apks downloaded from market by two different download URL(They have different activation code in params).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to use the above mentioned activation code for apps that can be downloaded from google play store itself? Because, we have a problem in distributing apk separately.